# VSTO - Outlook 2007 How do I show a form inside the Outlook window?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-2007, outlook-addin, outlook-2007-addin

I'm using VSTO with Outlook 2007 and I need to show a form (or a user control) inside the main window in outlook when the user clicks a specific toolbar button, that is, I need it to appear in the same window that the reading pane appears and not to open in a window by itself. Is this possible?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yandos,

you can do this using Subclassing, this can be a complicated subject but a great primer is over at http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/additional_panel_Outlook.aspx

or you could use a comercial product that does that for you e.g, [add-in-express](http://www.add-in-express.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can create an Outlook Form Region. Here's one of the many resources available on the subject:

Walkthrough: Creating an Outlook Form Region
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa942741(VS.80).aspx

Comment: The problem here is that the Form Regions seem to be attached to message types, and I couldn't find any way to show them from my toolbar button. I want the form to appear when I click that button and ONLY then.